# MySQL Chef: NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to use the MySQL cookbook from the supermarket but having some exceptions

My config is very basic:

**Recipe:**

```
mysql_service 'foo' do
  port '3306'
  version '5.5'
  initial_root_password 'changeme'
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

**Metadata.rb**

```
depends 'mysql', '~> 6.0'
```

**Berksfile**

```
cookbook 'mysql', '~> 6.0'
```

I using Kitchen with vagrant and centos 6 as a platform but getting this exception:

```
         Recipe: test-mysql::default
         * mysql_service[foo] action create

           ================================================================================
           Error executing action `create` on resource 'mysql_service[foo]'
           ================================================================================

           NoMethodError
           -------------
           undefined method `set' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000000037bc818>

           Cookbook Trace: (most recent call first)
           ----------------------------------------
           /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:265:in `pkginfo'
           /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:388:in `package_name_for'
           /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:431:in `server_package'
           /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb:442:in `server_package_name'
           /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_base.rb:31:in `block in <class:MysqlServiceBase>'

           Resource Declaration:
           ---------------------
           # In /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test-mysql/recipes/default.rb

             1: mysql_service 'foo' do
             2:   port '3306'
             3:   version '5.5'
             4:   initial_root_password 'changeme'
             5:   action [:create, :start]
             6: end

           Compiled Resource:
           ------------------
           # Declared in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test-mysql/recipes/default.rb:1:in `from_file'

           mysql_service("foo") do
             action [:create, :start]
             default_guard_interpreter :default
             declared_type :mysql_service
             cookbook_name "test-mysql"
             recipe_name "default"
             port "3306"
             version "5.5"
             initial_root_password "changeme"
           end

           System Info:
           ------------
           chef_version=16.4.41
           platform=centos
           platform_version=6.10
           ruby=ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
           program_name=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
           executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client


       Running handlers:
       [2020-08-28T04:30:27+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       Running handlers complete
       [2020-08-28T04:30:27+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
       [2020-08-28T04:30:27+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       [2020-08-28T04:30:27+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
       [2020-08-28T04:30:27+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: mysql_service[foo] (test-mysql::default line 1) had an error: NoMethodError: undefined method `set' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000000037bc818>
```

I also tried with a more recent version of the cookbook but getting the same error

Comment: Cookbook trace seems to indicate that your machine is recognized as "debian" instead of CentOS mentioned in your question. See lines 442, 431, 388 in `helpers.rb`.

Comment: but from the logs, I can see Centos 6. chef_version=16.4.41
           platform=centos
           platform_version=6.10

Comment: Strangely enough, lines 442, 431, 388 in `cookbooks/mysql/libraries/helpers.rb` seems to set attributes for Debian OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found, it seems to be a compatibility issue between chef-client and mysql cookbook

By specifying in the Berksfile

```
cookbook 'mysql', '~> 7.0'
```

And in kitchen.yaml

```
product_name: chef
product_version: 14.12.9
```

Comment: It'd be better to use mysql 8.x and not pin to chef-14 at all

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a chef-client issue. I think you are using chef 14+.

That raises a few questions :

- What is the chef-client version used in your projects ?
- if its Chef 14+ , try using the latest supermarket cookbook
- Else, follow the instructions below.

In your `kitchen.yml`, try downgrading the `chef-client` under the `provisioner` section. Refer the below snippet :

```
provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  # You may wish to disable always updating cookbooks in CI or other testing environments.
  # For example:
  #   always_update_cookbooks: <%= !ENV['CI'] %>
  always_update_cookbooks: true
  product_name: chef
  product_version: 12.21
  chef_omnibus_url: "file:///opt/softwares/chef-12.21.26-1.el6.x86_64.rpm"
```

Then run your `kitchen destroy` and `kitchen converge`.

Comment: from the logs, you can see I am using chef_version=16.4.41, I also tried 8.0.0 and even 8.7.0 too

Comment: Try the provisioner settings in kitchen yml as described in the answer